# A question about taking derivative of convolution integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose I have a convolution integral writes as
$$\int_{\tau=0}^{t} \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left [- \frac{f(t)(x-x^{'})^2}{a(t-\tau)} \right] d x^{\prime} d \tau$$

where $a$ is some constant and $f(t)$ is some function of $t$.

Now if I want to take derivative w.r.t $t$ or $x$, that is

$$\frac{\partial \int_{\tau=0}^{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{a(t-\tau)} d x^{\prime} d \tau}{\partial t}$$

or

$$\frac{\partial \int_{\tau=0}^{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{a(t-\tau)} d x^{\prime} d \tau}{\partial x }$$

can I take the partial derivative inside the integral i.e. do the derivative before evaluating the definite integral?

How about integrate over $t$ or $x$？

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't there some issues with even the definition? The integral with respect to neither $x$ (being over an infinite interval) nor $\tau$ (having a singularity at 0) converge. My guess is that, whatever context this came from, you have to be careful about interpreting these objects, let alone taking derivatives or integrals of them.

Comment: Assuming you solve the issues that your integrals don't converge at their upper limits, in order to integrate, you can just integrate by parts

Comment: @Jose27 made some changes

Comment: With the edits the answer (at least for derivatives), is yes you can just take the derivatives inside (though with the $t$-derivative, you have to account for the upper limit depending on $t$, but this is a Leibniz rule thing). Are you familiar with how you interchange derivatives and integrals in general (via the dominated convergence theorem)?

Comment: For integrals, the issue is a little "easier": your function will define (at least if $f$ is nice enough) a bounded continuous function (it better if you're taking derivatives of it!), so the issue is: Over what domains are you integrating your $x,t$ variables? If it's a bounded domain, there's no issues. If it's unbounded, you may need to get some more detailed information about the decay in $x,t$.